# Javascript ES6, best way to remove item from array if it exists or add if doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm writing some code here to add an element on an array with the following logic

If the element exists on the array, the function should remove the element from the array and return the array without the given element, otherwise it should return the array with the given element appended on it.

Having this in mind, I'm thinking if there's a better way to do this, this is the code I've writed to do this.

```js
function filterArray(arr, obj, key) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i][key] === obj[key]) {
      const newArr = [...arr]
      newArr.splice(i, 1)
      return newArr
    }
  }
  return [...arr, obj]
}

const fruits = [
  { id: 1, fruit: "Apple" },
  { id: 2, fruit: "Banana" },
  { id: 3, fruit: "Pineapple" }
]

const removedBanana = filterArray(fruits, {
  id: 3,
  fruit: "Banana"
}, "fruit")

const addedStrawberry = filterArray(fruits, {
  id: 4,
  fruit: "Strawberry"
}, "fruit")

console.log(removedBanana) // [ { id: 1, fruit: 'Apple' }, { id: 3, fruit: 'Pineapple' } ]
console.log(addedStrawberry)
// [
//   { id: 1, fruit: 'Apple' },
//   { id: 2, fruit: 'Banana' },
//   { id: 3, fruit: 'Pineapple' },
//   { id: 4, fruit: 'Strawberry' }
// ]
```

There's a better way to do this on ES6?

**EDIT**
If possible, I want to iterate the array only one time, making an O(n) algorithm

Comment: do you want to mutate the array?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes

Comment: your code shows a new array ...

Comment: Ops, sorry @NinaScholz, I don't want to mutate, I want to create a new one

Answer (score 8):

This approach mutates the array by looking for the index and splice if found or push the object to the array. The result has the same object reference than the handed over array.

```js
function filterArray(array, object, key) {
    var index = array.findIndex(o => o[key] === object[key]);
    if (index === -1) array.push(object);
    else array.splice(index, 1);
    return array;
}

const
    fruits = [{ id: 1, fruit: "Apple" }, { id: 2, fruit: "Banana" }, { id: 3, fruit: "Pineapple" }];

console.log(filterArray(fruits, { id: 3, fruit: "Banana" }, "fruit"));
console.log(filterArray(fruits, { id: 4, fruit: "Strawberry" }, "fruit"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For a nonmutating approach, you could get a copy in the head of the function and perform the same as above.

```
function filterArray([...array], object, key) {
```

```js
function filterArray(array, object, key) {
    var index = array.findIndex(o => o[key] === object[key]);
    if (index === -1) array.push(object);
    else array.splice(index, 1);
    return array;
}

const
    fruits = [{ id: 1, fruit: "Apple" }, { id: 2, fruit: "Banana" }, { id: 3, fruit: "Pineapple" }];

console.log(filterArray(fruits, { id: 3, fruit: "Banana" }, "fruit"));
console.log(filterArray(fruits, { id: 4, fruit: "Strawberry" }, "fruit"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Gonna have to move to some timezone 12h ahead Dusseldorf to get a chance to score some rep.. Would do that with ternary operator, but `splice()`/`push()` couple seems to work the best in this particular case (especially, together with `findIndex()`). Upvoted.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, a ternary does not work, because of the different parameters.

Comment: ternary operator [works](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/OJPZWoe?editors=0012) perfectly for 'mutating' approach

Comment: ...just as well as for non-mutating with spreading syntax within function parameters

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.some()` to check if the object exists, and if it does  filter it out. If not, add it.

```js
function filterArray(arr, obj, key) {
  return arr.some(o => obj[key] === o[key]) ? // if you can find the object
    arr.filter(o => obj[key] !== o[key]) // remove it
    :  
    [...arr, obj] // or add it if not
}

const fruits = [{"id":1,"fruit":"Apple"},{"id":2,"fruit":"Banana"},{"id":3,"fruit":"Pineapple"}]

const removedBanana = filterArray(fruits, { id: 3, fruit: "Banana" }, "fruit")
const addedStrawberry = filterArray(fruits, { id: 4, fruit: "Strawberry" }, "fruit")

console.log(removedBanana) // [ { id: 1, fruit: 'Apple' }, { id: 3, fruit: 'Pineapple' } ]
console.log(addedStrawberry)
// [
//   { id: 1, fruit: 'Apple' },
//   { id: 2, fruit: 'Banana' },
//   { id: 3, fruit: 'Pineapple' },
//   { id: 4, fruit: 'Strawberry' }
// ]
```

Comment: `filter()` looping through the entire array and `some()` looping till the match make it 2 passes in the worst case. Still O(n), yet doesn't seem to be the best performant solution. I guess, [there's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59682467/11299053) a shorter way.

Comment: Note the difference between the solutions - mine doesn't mutate the array. To keep things immutable without filter, you'll still need 1st to find the index of the item - O(n), and if it exists, copy the array (O(n)) as well. So immutable will require O(2n) -> O(n).

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution for this question:

```
function addObjToArray (arr, obj, key) {
  const resultArr = arr.filter(arrObj => arrObj[key] !== obj[key])
  if (resultArr.length === arr.length) resultArr.push(obj)
  return resultArr
}
```

The `filter` method will return an array with just objects that are different of `obj[key]`. If filtered array is equal to original array, it push the object to `resultArr`, else, just will return the initial `resultArr`.

This is solution from my work colleague (https://stackoverflow.com/users/12691758/guilherme-ca%c3%a7ador-monteiro).

What you think?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/users/12691758/guilherme-ca%c3%a7ador-monteiro

Answer (score 0):

By your requirements, and the additional requirement -- in comments -- that the collection should *mutate*, you would have a better tool by using an ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const fruits = new Map([
  { id: 1, fruit: "Apple" },
  { id: 2, fruit: "Banana" },
  { id: 3, fruit: "Pineapple" }
].map (o => [o.fruit, o]));
fruits.key = "fruit"; // register the key field once
fruits.toggleItem = function (obj) {
    if (!this.delete(obj[this.key])) this.set(obj[this.key], obj);
}

fruits.toggleItem({id: 3, fruit: "Banana"});

console.log([...fruits.values()]);

fruits.toggleItem({id: 4, fruit: "Strawberry"});

console.log([...fruits.values()]);
```